# Voice command for android music player app

Tags: android, voice-recognition, audio-player, android-music-player

I am working on an android music player and I wanna have hand-free voice commands,i.e., don't need to press any button to start recording. the app should keep listening all the time. Is there a way ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Houndify SDK for voice recognition. It can be triggered without a button press, and it has music domains for searching and controlling music playback.

http://www.soundhound.com/houndify